# Magento search returns no results, but filters attributes?

Tags: search, magento

I've uploaded a screenshot of my issue. I'm not really sure why my search results aren't returning products, but the attributes for the available are shown.

I'm using magento 1.4.2- Has anyone encountered this?
[image]

EDIT// I've also cleared my cache/rebuilt indexes multiple times.

Comment: enable template/path hints and see if your template file is being properly called to display the products based on the filter.

Comment: I actually ended up copying all folders relating to catalog search from 1.4.1 and it managed to show. I'll look out for that in the future, though.

Comment: Please turn your comment into a real answer below. You can mark it as accepted after two days. That will make the question go away from the Unanswered Questions tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just re-installed a portion of 1.4.2 and corrected this issue.